# Does Java HashMap method containsKey calculate hash of the passed object in each call

Tags: java, hashmap

Does `boolean containsKey(Object key)` of `HashMap` class calculate hash of the passed object each time I call it? If yes, is there anyway to avoid it for next calls?

Comment: There's a way to test this -- by simply overriding the key class's `hashCode()` method.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, it does. No, you can't avoid it.

If it's expensive to calculate you should change `hashCode()` to cache the computed value so it's only calculated the first time it's called. It's supposed to be a fast function. Don't expect callers to try to avoid calling it too much.

Answer (score 4):

From the [JDK6 source](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/HashMap.java#351):

```
351     public boolean containsKey(Object key) {
352         return getEntry(key) != null;
353     }

360     final Entry<K,V> getEntry(Object key) {
361         int hash = (key == null) ? 0 : hash(key.hashCode());
362         for (Entry<K,V> e = table[indexFor(hash, table.length)];
363              e != null;
364              e = e.next) {
365             Object k;
366             if (e.hash == hash &&
367                 ((k = e.key) == key || (key != null && key.equals(k))))
368                 return e;
369         }
370         return null;
371     }
```

So the conclusion is **every time** if `key` is not null.